# Address of static global variable changed?

Tags: c++, c

I am facing a strange issue. I have a module, say `x.c` and this is the sample snippet code:

```
typedef struct lat {    
     int x;
     int y;
     int z;   
} lat;

static lat x;

static void populate( int x, int y, int z ) {
     lat *pLat = &x;        
     printf(" The value of pLat is %p \n", pLat );

     pLat->x = x;
     pLat->y = y;
     pLat->z = z;
}

extern  dump_report( void  *pPayload) {
    lat *pLat = &x;        
    printf(" The value of pLat is %p \n", pLat );

    memcpy( pPayload, pLat, sizeof(lat) );  
}
```

The address of global variable is different ( `printf`s), in the two functions? `populate()` is called internally within the module and gives correct values, while the `dump_report()` is called from a different module and yields a wrong address of global variable and zeroed values.

Can someone let me know if I am doing anything incorrectly?

Comment: How did you determine that the address printed by `populate` is the correct address? (Hint: it isn't.)

Comment: Are you using a C or C++ compiler - your code looks like C but you've tagged with C++ too, which I think is unwarranted.

Answer (score 13):

You are masking your global `x` with the local `int x` from your function definition:

```
static void populate( int x, int y, int z )
```

Simply rename `int x`.

Comment: Note that if the compiler were issuing proper diagnostics, the assignment of `&x` to a pointer of incompatible type would have been an error; neither C nor C++ has such an automatic conversion.

Comment: Well, "proper diagnostics" allows for warnings, and many C compilers do allow such conversions with just a warning rather than an error. The OP does need to actually check any generated warnings, though.

Answer (score 4):

Local variables take precedence over globals. so you must rename your `int x` or `static lat x`[image]

And I would suggest you use a better compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Global static variable is stored in [.BSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss), as it is initialised to zero. But [Local variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable) is stored in Stack memory. So the memory addresses will be different. Both variables are having same name but they are stored in different memory, as they are different in programming context. Renaming variable will serve your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If a global and local variable are of same name, then local variable is given preference over global variable every time.